# ColorTranslator.FromOle(0x8000000f) number too large

Tags: c#, colors, vb6

I'm trying to update an old VB6 program and I came across this line

```
frmMain.Command1(X).BackColor = &H8000000F
```

When trying to convert this to C# I came up with

```
this.Command1[X].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(0x8000000f);
```

This doesn't seem to work as the hex number is too large for .FromOle as it takes an int, but this number is too large for an int. Do you have any suggestions on other ways that I can do this or get around this?

Thanks

Comment: The lowest order byte in Ole is used as a system color index. If you drop the 0f do you get the desired results? (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/131101)

Comment: [vbButtonFace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265064(v=vs.60).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&H8000000F` is the button face color, and in C# :

```
this.Command1[X].BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace
```

Comment: That's what I was after. Cheers!